# Kubernetes - Specify Instance Using nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to specify a specific instance instead of a pool of instances using `nodeSelector` in Kubernetes?

If not, what would be the best way to provision a Redis Cluster with each node having at least 30GB of memory. Can this be accomplished using the `resources` attribute?

By the way, I'm currently creating 6 pools with 1 instance in each and then specifying that in the config but it doesn't look right:

```
nodeSelector:
  cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: my-pool-1
```

Answer (score 13):

The kubelet should automatically add a label for the hostname, using `kubernetes.io/hostname`.

With that in mind, you can pin a pod to a specific host using:

```
nodeSelector:
  kubernetes.io/hostname: "<hostname>"
```

I would question if this is a good idea, however.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use `nodeSelector` at all in this case. The idea is that you provide your *requirements* and let the scheduler decide which nodes to use.

If each of you Pods actually need 30GB of memory then specify a [resource request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-ram-container/#assigning-cpu-and-ram-resources-to-a-container) in your Pod(template) for the container that needs it:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - ...    
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "30Gi"
```

Now if a Node has more than 60GB RAM it may have 2 of your Pods scheduled. If for some reason you also need to make sure that each Node runs at most 1 your Pods of this type you can use specify an [inter-pod anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/) in your Pod(template):

```
...
metadata:
  name: with-pod-affinity
  annotations: >
    {
      "podAntiAffinity": {
        "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": [
          {
            "topologyKey": "kubernetes.io/hostname"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
spec:
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Janos Lenart. I haven't tried inter-pod anti-affinity but it seems like something I need. Will give it a shot.